# How to obtain numeric value from a custom field by get_post_meta?

Tags: php, wordpress, get, numbers, custom-fields

This might be a stupid question, but the trivial thing is that the most common function fails to work.

By this code I have set up my custom field:

```
/**
 * Extra custom fields
*/

function ccf_create_custom_field() {
 $args = array(
'id' => 'custom_cost_field',
'label' => __( 'Product Cost', 'woocommerce' ),
'class' => 'ccf-cost-field',
'type' => 'number',
);

woocommerce_wp_text_input( $args );
}

/* Display Fields */
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'ccf_create_custom_field' );


/* Save Fields */
add_action('woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'woocommerce_product_custom_fields_save');

function woocommerce_product_custom_fields_save($post_id) {

/* Custom Product Number Field */
$woocommerce_custom_product_number_field = $_POST['custom_cost_field'];
if (!empty($woocommerce_custom_product_number_field))
    update_post_meta($post_id, 'custom_cost_field', esc_attr($woocommerce_custom_product_number_field));
}

require_once "custom.php";
```

This is my custom.php:

```
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<?php wc_get_template_part('content', 'single-product'); ?>
<?php

// Display the value of custom product number field
echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'custom_cost_field', true);
?>
<?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
```

This is the function that obtains values:

```
$costs = (ceil((get_post_meta($product, 'custom_cost_field', true))/100)*85);
```

Although the custom field has a value saved of for example of 1090, the get_post_meta does not return anything, as the value in my table is always 0 for costs. I absolutely don´t understand this :S.

Any ideas? Am I missing something out?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this is the answer:

```
$custom_cost = ceil(get_post_meta(get_the_id(), 'custom_cost_field', true));
```

For custom fields, always keep the "get_the_id()" in the function and it will work. Thats the whole trick - never keep a variable (product, post) in there.

If you have obtained the ID via a different function before, it still won´t work - you must keep the "get_the_id()" in the function.